# ¿Cómo separar una cadena sin perder al elemento de separación?

Tags: java, string, regex, split

Mi duda es sencilla, quiero realizar algo similar a esto:

```
String cadena = "Hola-Mundo";
String[] separacion = cadena.split("-");
```

Lo cual me devuelve ["Hola","Mundo"]

Pero el resultado que me gustaría obtener es ["Hola","-","Mundo"]

(Ojo que estoy usando java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fijate si esto te sirve, funciona para tu ejemplo: "Hola-Mundo"

```
String s = "Hola-Mundo";
String[] partes = s.replaceAll("-", " - ").split(" ");
```

El **replaceAll("-", " - ")** machea con **-** y lo remplaza con ' - ' es decir, agrega espacios antes y después de **-**

Después el **split(" ")** separa usando los espacios en blanco.

Comment: Ok, esa solución parece funcionar, pero si en el método "split" coloco una expresión regular más estructurada funcionará igualmente? ya que creo que el método "replaceAll" no valida expresiones regulares.

Comment: El primer parámetro de replaceAll es una expresión regular https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String 
 se puede buscar patrones más complejos

Comment: Este es el enlace correcto a la documentacion del método replaceall 
 https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

Comment: :0 muchas gracias, lo voy a intentar implementar con esta forma

Answer (score 2):

`cadena.split("(?=-)|(?<=-)");`

Funciona para el caso, pero antes que nada un breve paso a paso...

`cadena.split("");`

El cual basicamente devolvera uno a uno cada caracter del `String`:

`[H, o, l, a, -, M, u, n, d, o]`

---

Ahora modificaré la *REGEX* basándola en una búsqueda *LookAhead* `?=` (*cualquier palabra que esté precedida por un dash* `-`):

`cadena.split("(?=-)");`

Mostrandonos:

`[Hola, -Mundo]`

---

Vuelvo a modificar mi *REGEX* pero ahora especifico que ésta busque en una forma *LookBehind* `?<=`, es decir, buscar las palabras que estén seguidas por un *dash* `-`:

`cadena.split("?<=-");`

Arrojando:

`[Hola-, Mundo]`

---

Ahora poniéndolo todo junto para que la *REGEX* encuentre palabras seguidas ó (`|`) precedidas por el *dash* `-`:

`cadena.split("(?=-)|(?<=-)");`

Imprimiria el array resultante como:

`[Hola, -, Mundo]`

Answer (score 0):

```
//FelipedelosH

public class main {

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    //Cadena original separada por el caracter -
    String cadena = "Hola-Mundo";
    
    
    
    //String temporal
    String temporal = "";
    //Cadena de separacion
    String[] separacion = new String[(cadena.split("-").length)+1];
    //Contador para guardar las palabras separadas
    int contador = 0;
    
    
    //Se recorre toda la caneda con un for
    for(int i=0;i<cadena.length();i++) {
        
        //Se analiza el caracter
        char chr = cadena.charAt(i);
    
        if(chr == '-') {
            //Se guarda en el array
            separacion[contador] = temporal;
            separacion[contador+1] = "-";
            contador = contador + 1;
            //Borral el temporal
            temporal = "";
            
        }else {
            temporal = temporal + cadena.charAt(i);
            
        }
    }
    
    //Se guarda la ultima parabra
    separacion[contador+1] = temporal;
    
    
    
    //Se muestra el resultado final
    for(int i=0;i<separacion.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(separacion[i]);
    }
    
  }
}
```